# How to convert Document type result to Java Object?

Tags: java, ibm-cloud

I'm new to Java and in one of my pocs, I'm getting Document type results when using the 'Findresult' class to query cloudant db, but I want the result to be converted to a Java Object, so I wrote a pojo class for it.
I'm not sure how to cast an object from a document.

This is the query where I'm using FindResult class(import com.ibm.cloud.cloudant.v1.model.FindResult):

```js
FindResult queryResult = cloudantConfig.clientBuilder().postFind(findOptions).execute()
                            .getResult();
HouseModal houseModal = queryResult.getDocs().get(0);
```

'Type mismatch: cannot convert from Document to HouseModal' is the error I'm getting.
Can somebody assist me through the process of converting a document to an object?

Comment: A shot into the dark: `HouseModal houseModal = (HouseModal) queryResult.getDocs().get(0);` If it does not work, then you have to cast it manually.

Comment: @Reporter getting an error like Cannot cast from Document to HouseModal

Comment: Then you have cast it manually by using setter methods from HouseModal, whatever it is.